# Cannot reach to shared folder of Fedora host from Virtualbox Windows 10 guest

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, fedora, shared-folders

I've decided to give Fedora a whirl and installed the Fedora Workstation 26. I also need to use Windows every now and then for MS office suite.

I've got a working Windows 10 VM running in Virtualbox with guest additions installed, but I cannot reach the shared folder of Fedora 26 host. When I try to reach \\VBOXSVR or \\vboxsvr or \\VBOXSRV or \\vboxsrv or \\10.0.2.2, it says it cannot reach the path.

Here is the dump of the ipconfig from Windows guest:

```
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : aspire.local
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::146d:d785:2538:9896%2
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :2001:0:4137:9e76:2c87:298c:f5ff:fdf0
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c87:298c:f5ff:fdf0%11
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

And here is the ifconfig from Fedora host:

```
enp2s0f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether b8:70:f4:ef:ae:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 40  bytes 2852 (2.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 40  bytes 2852 (2.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.124.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.124.255
    ether 52:54:00:25:8e:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0b1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::db09:384b:bd5a:4711  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 74:2f:68:aa:e6:41  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1656  bytes 844896 (825.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1637  bytes 291472 (284.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I can ping 10.0.2.2 from guest OS, but cannot reach the path.

I've also tried to disable SELinux (setenforce 0) and adding my host user to vboxusers group, none of the above seems to be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you configured the shared folders with the VirtualBox machine definition?

Comment: Yes, I've defined it in the GUI. And before you ask it, yes I've restarted both the host and the guest machines.

Comment: And you clicked the automount checkbox?

Comment: Yup, indeed I did.

Comment: This "just works" for me.  Sucks that you're having difficulties.  I have Fedora 24, latest VBox, VBox kernel modules are loaded, Windows 10 Guest with latest Guest Additions.  I configured the machine with the VBox GUI... Launched the Windows 10 Guest and the Shared Folder appears as a network folder.  Have you tried creating a new minimal Guest with a Shared Folder?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that problem is sourced from the guest additions of Virtualbox itself. I've received and installed the update today and problem gone away!